# WordPress adding paragraph tag around image

Tags: wordpress

First, I am new to WordPress, second I have read all of the posts, blogs, etc. related to this issue and so far nothing makes sense.

I have a simple three page site.  All three pages use this basic code at the top of the page to display a banner type image:

```
<div class="banner-section" style="background-image: url('/wp-content/themes/company/images/home-banner.jpg');">
    <div class="banner-content align-centered" style="padding-top: 12.05%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-6 small-6 columns"><img src="/wp-content/themes/company/images/home-banner-k-logo.png" /></div>
            <div class="medium-6 small-6 columns"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/company-new-combined.png" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img class="main-img" src="/wp-content/themes/company/images/home-banner.jpg" />
</div>
```

Two of the pages work just fine.  ONLY ONE of the pages, the contact form page, WordPress is wrapping the image in a paragraph tag.  Why only this page?  I could hack it by wrapping it myself and set some CSS to remove the margins.  But why?  Why would WordPress be inconsistent here?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress automatically inserts `<p>` and `</p>` tags which separate content breaks.

To disable the wpautop filter, you can use:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: Sorry, need WordPress for Dummies/Newbies version.  Where do I put that?  I read about a php file you change but how do I get to that?

Comment: Add it in functions.php at the very end, wp-content/themes/{your-theme-name}/functios.php

Answer (score -1):

It is might be because you are using contact form plugin or something , anyway you can add your own style but please do it on the child theme.

Comment: I took that out of the HTML and problem still there.  Is the plugin still loading on the page?